# Impact of visitors on a 'noindex' page

Tags: seo, noindex, page-views

I have a page which has a 'noindex' attribute. So google will not index this page at all. But this page has lots of visitors. Does this number of page views have any impact on my SEO?

Comment: How do visitors get to that page?

Comment: if this page contains internal links to your site and users will click on them, in this case it will be affected

Comment: I can't imagine it having any negative impact for your SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody will give guarantees when answering your question. My opinion is that yes, pages that are closed from indexing still have an indirect impact on SEO.

For example, Google collects data from Chrome users from the entire site, not just from the indexed pages: [Core Web Vitals Might Include Noindexed Pages](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/core-web-vitals-noindex/395578/). Next, you need to answer the question: «Does Google use behavioral data from pages closed from indexing?». My opinion is that yes, it does. There is no confirmation either for or against.

Comment: thanks. seems that  it has some impact.

Answer (score 2):

No, your pageviews on a 'noindex' page will not have any specific impact on your SEO efforts if it does not fall into the below cases:

1. Your pageviews do not come as direct traffic.
2. Your 'noindex' page doesn't contain internal 'index' links that users spend a lot of time or interact with.
3. Your 'noindex' page doesnt contain links that link internally or externally with a 'dofollow' tag.

If you could provide more information on why you choose to 'noindex' a performing page and above use-cases, a better answer could be provided.

Please do note that there is no exact answer available in the public domain or any answer provided by Google.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a useful note. As I said earlier, it is a 'customer-only' page so I do not want it to be appeared on google results. Customers enter the page directly and it has a high traffic. I wanted to know whether this traffic can benefit the entire website.

Comment: You could benefit by using internal/do-follow links but the extent and timeline are not clear as no public information is available.

You could run an experiment and see how your rankings are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Timur pointed to an article [SEJ Article with John Mueller of Google](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/core-web-vitals-noindex/395578/#close).  I think it's valuable to read the entire article for context.

First, Mueller states "I don’t know for sure how we would do things with a noindex..."

The question is asked in the sessions is if a noindex page that is slow might impact their core web vitals rank.

Mueller responds, "Does Google have data points for the other pages there? And then you can kind of figure out like okay, it can recognize that there is separate kinds of pages and can treat them individually. And if that’s the case, then I don’t see a problem with that."

But with a small website he says "If it’s a smaller website where we just don’t have a lot of signals for the website then those noindex pages could be playing a role there as well."

I think Mueller's response is an indicator of when or if Google will use a noindex page in the calculation.  If it's a small site, and they have no other data, then it appears they will use a noindex page.  But if it's a large site, and they have plenty of other data points, they may not.

However, as Mueller says, "I don’t know for sure how we would do things with a noindex".

In and of itself, I don't think the noindex tag impacts SEO.  However, the content of the page and the user's experience, depending on the size of your website might.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems that noindex pages have kind of impact on the website. however, it is not clear. you said about a slow page; conversely, my page is a well-designed page which has a lot of traffic, and may or may not affect the website positively. I managed to 'noindex' it because it is a customer-only page, not a public one.